# Can we integrate SharePoint On-premises with Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to create a linked service in ADF(Azure data factory) to integrate it witrh sharepoint On-premise

I have registered the sharepoint On-premise application on Azure active directory.....but still not able to integrate it with adf

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, currently Azure Data Factory does not support interaction with SharePoint on-premise.
For other workarounds, I would recommend trying [connect your Azure Databricks workspace to your on-premises network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network).